# Change background color of selected code in IPython Notebook

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the [Base16 Ocean dark](https://github.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook/blob/master/ipython-2/output/base16-ocean-dark.css) theme on `IPytho`n Notebook.

The background color of selected text doesn't contrast very well, making it difficult to tell if it's selected:

[image]

On the default settings, this does not occur:

[image]

Please let me know how to change the background color of selected code on `IPython` Notebook to a more clear one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the following code in a notebook to find out the jupyter config folder on your system, if you don't know it yet:

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_dir
jupyter_dir = jupyter_config_dir()
print(jupyter_dir)
```

In the jupyter config folder, find /custom/custom.css, modify the following line:

```
.cm-s-ipython div.CodeMirror-selected {background: #384151 !important;}
```

I use '#3366ff' here, you may use whatever background color that suits your need.

Comment: It actually works: css edit & save -> notebook reload -> we're good!

Answer (score 2):

All is well with jimmyazrael answer, but if you're using Jupyter 5.0 from within Anaconda3 you will find your css file at:

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\cutom\custom.css
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Mine was I bit more complicated. Couldn't find it in any mentioned folder, thus after searching my system for "custom.css", I have found many of this! It is likely because I had upgraded/downgraded my environment multiple times.

So, in the end, I open the file in:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\notebook-6.1.5-py37haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom\custom.css
```

Pasted the line:

```
.cm-s-ipython div.CodeMirror-selected {background: #384151 !important;}
```

Saved and restarted Jupyter. It worked!